# About normal operators' spectral measure.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In fact, I want to prove a result in functional analysis about normal operators' spectral measure. It states as:

If $N$ is a normal operator on Hilbert space $H$, then the spectral measure of $N$ is regular, in the sense that for each Borel set $S$, $E(S)$ is the projection onto the smallest subspace containing the union of the ranges of the projections $E(T)$ for $T$ a closed subset of $S$.

Comment: Hint: singletons are closed.

Comment: Are  you sure you copied the problem correctly? As Wojowu points out this has nothing to do with Borel sets.

Comment: maybe my statement of the problem caused  misunderstanding. I restated it just now as above. I still have no idea with the help of Wojowu's hint.

Comment: @LiJingyang This still seems wrong. Wojowu's hint is that singletons are closed - so if every closed subset of $E_1$ is also a subset of $E_2$, then every *element* of $E_1$ is an *element* of $E_2$ (since $x\in E_1$ implies $\{x\}\subseteq E_1$ which implies $\{x\}\subseteq E_2$ since $\{x\}$ is closed). This still has nothing to do with Borel sets.

Comment: Oh, what a silly quenstion. my mind is just out of its mind. Thank you Noah Schweber.

Comment: @LiJingyang Note that just restricting to non-singletons doesn't help. First of all, the statement is now *false* if $E_1$ has only one element (since then $\mathbb{M}$ is empty) and that element is not in $E_2$. Second, if $E_1$ has at least two elements, then - since every two-element set is closed - the above argument still goes through. Where are you getting this problem from?

Comment: @user46944 Sorry, the "above argument" referred to the argument showing that $E_1\subset E_2$ trivially; *not* the argument showing that the problem as currently stated is false. (Note that $E_1$ is not assumed to be closed, so you still have to argue as "for each $x\in E_1$ there is $y\in E_1$, $y\not=x$, so $\{x, y\}\subseteq E_2$".)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh I see!

Comment: @NoahSchweber, user46944,Wojowu, thank you all. I have to state my problem in its original form now.